# Academic referees: course organisor vs project supervisor?

Tags: phd, application

I am currently applying for a PhD at a University in the UK.

As part of the application process, I am asked to give the name of two academic referees.

During my recent Master course, I had the opportunity to undertake several (at least 3) projects within different laboratories.

**My question: is it preferable to ask one my past projects supervisors to serve as an academic referee (who supervised me for some weeks only) or should I ask the Master course organisor (who has a better overview of my work and achievements during my Master studies) to be academic referee?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the names who know about your academic background and research ability very well. So he/she could be your Master degree professors or supervisors. In my point of view, you should provide a name who was your project supervisor as well as professor.

As per your question, I can suggest you the following two names.

1. One from your master course department (who has a better overview of your work and achievements during your Master studies)
2. One who supervised you for some weeks. Because short term project supervisor would write good about your research ability.